# Which is the future limit on schedule notifications on OneSignal

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, onesignal

I'm trying to use OneSignal to schedule notifications to the future, the problem is if I schedule the notification with `send_after` for example to 2019 the api returns this message

```
Schedule Notifications may not be scheduled so far in the future.
```

This is the setup example:

```
var message = {
                    app_id:  config.get('oneSignal:appId'),
                    headings: {"en": "head"},
                    contents: {"en": "content"},
                    filters: [
                        {"field": "tag", "key": "email", "relation": "=", "value": user.mail}
                    ],
                    send_after: "2019-06-01 14:00:00 GMT-0700"
                };
```

And this is the response message

```
Response:
{ errors: [ 'Schedule Notifications may not be scheduled so far in the future.' ] }
```

Which is the limit? And it is possible to 'extend'?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Once ask that question. This is response

[image]

Comment: After several test the maximum time to schedule a notification is 364 years

Comment: After testing it, the error occurs after 29 days (not inclusive).

Comment: According to https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/sending-notifications#step-3-scheduling it is 30 days.

Answer (score 2):

I think their limit might have changed. After testing i can only get it to send notifications up to **one month** in the future.